# Angular min and max time not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to create some form where there is a start time and end time, I am using [angular strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##timepickers) for that. as expected the start time should be less then the end time and the end time should be greater then the start time ==>

```
start time < end time
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a2w5JTrkM9No0z8RD5oE?p=preview) I have created, and for some reason it is not working as expected.

Comment: what you mean by : not working as expected

Comment: That the both timepickers not limiting each other. See the plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with this control but I think you need to use `{{}}` and there's a little logical problem, too. So instead of

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="8" 
       ng-model="time1" max-time="time2" 
       ...>

<input type="text" class="form-control" size="8" 
       ng-model="time2" max-time="time1" 
       ...>
```

Use the following

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="8" 
       ng-model="time1" 
       ...>

<input type="text" class="form-control" size="8" 
       ng-model="time2" min-time="{{ time1 }}" 
       ...>
```

The logical problem was that you had `max-time` set on both controls, referring to each other's value. So time1 couldn't be greater than time2 nor time2 greater than time1. It should be sufficient to let `time1` be any time and just evaluate that `time2` is no less than `time1`.

Also, it's annoying that changing `time1` value is not causing re-evaluation of `time2`'s `min-time` instantly but only after you change the `time2` itself. I don't know if it's supposed to work this way, it can be related to `Error:[$rootScope:inprog]` your Plunker is throwing frequently.